# Selenium WebDriver Python: How to stop 'send_keys' from hitting return after sending a string

Tags: python, macos, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate signing into a website using Twitter, and to enter the twitter login info I am using the `elem.send_keys("username")` method in Selenium WebDriver.

The method seems to also 'hit' enter after sending the string, which is a problem because it causes the login form to be submitted before I have entered the password, and the page refreshes, removing the already-entered username, preventing login.

How do I send keys without enter being also submitted afterwards?
Thanks.

Python: 3.4.1,
Selenium: 2.42.1,
OS: Mac OSX 10.9.4

Edit:

This is the way I have written all interactions with elements in the browser, wrapped in a try/except to prevent StaleElementReference errors:

```
found = False
while not found:
    try:
        enterPassword = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
        enterPassword.send_keys(twPassword)
        found = True
    except:
        pass
```

Could this be the problem?

Comment: `.send_keys("username")`  does not hit enter, there must be something else wrong with your code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please see my edit to see how I called the method

Comment: where do you click/submit?

Comment: That is written in the same format, with a .click() instead of .send_keys(), but it's irrelevant, because the form is refreshed when the username/password are entered,so clicking submit would not work anyway

Comment: does twpassword has a \n in it?cos send_keys does not hit enter by itself.

Comment: It is relevant because you may be clicking the wrong element, send_keys does not hit return

Comment: @vks Yes that must be the problem! As I am retrieving the username/password from separate lines of a text file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you test if this submits on your end? (It doesn't on mine)

```
from selenium import webdriver as driver

browser = driver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
print browser.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys('Searchstring')
```

On a side Note:
Waiting for elements to be present should be done with explicit waits.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'someid')))
```

[ReadTheDocs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html)